# PHP HTML to PDF free convertor Resources

Tags: php, pdf

What is the best PHP HTML to PDF free converter around, not just in terms of functionality but also in terms of resource usage and speed

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/), an HTML to PDF converter written in PHP. No external dependencies, it supports complex tables, images and even external style sheets.

http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/

Comment: DOMPDF started showing problems since php 5.2 (generating segfaults with certain html input) and probably isn't the most resource-friendly html2pdf available. Its a nice solution nonetheless (supported on shared hosting, etc).

Comment: I thought this issue was only when trying to use it from the command-line.

Answer (score 3):

**[Have a look at open-souce fpdf library.](http://www.fpdf.org/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really clever about it, you could programmatically create a new Google doc containing your HTML and CSS, then programmatically export it as a PDF. No resource usage on your part, and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:
http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf

We recently used this on a project with quite a bit of luck.  I don't know that it will go straight from HTML to PDF like you are looking for, but it is a good set of tools.